# Applying a function with multiple inputs using Map? (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary, ghc

G'day guys,

Trying currently to finish up a bit of homework I'm working on, and having an issue where I'm trying to apply map across a function that accepts multiple inputs.

so in the case I'm using processList f (x:xs) = map accelerateList f xs x xs

processList is given a floating value (f) and a List that it sorts into another List

Accelerate List takes a floating value (f) a List and a List Object through which it returns another List Object

I know my Accelerate List code is correct, but I cannot for the life of me get the syntax for this code working:

```
processList :: Float -> [Object] -> [Object]
accelerate f [] = []
accelerate f [x] = [(accelerateForce f x x)]
accelerate f (x:xs) = map accelerateList f xs x xs
```

Any ideas? I've been scratching my head for about 3 hours now. I know it's something *really* simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of you will probably want to use some parenthesis here:

```
map accelerateList f xs x xs
```

The function `map` takes exactly two arguments (not five), so you should do something like this for example:

```
map (accelerateList f xs x) xs
```

But on the other hand, that doesn't fit with your function signatures. The problem is probably that you haven't structured your solution in a good enough way. Might be a separate question, but explaining what you're trying to accomplish with the accelerate-function (or which ever one is the "top" one) would certainly help.

Comment: I absolutely thought it was a structure error, thank you.

I'm attempting to map a function that compares two elements in a list, across an entire list of objects.

So for each object I have to compare it to each other object in the list to calculate a motion for it.

Comment: With a bit of buggerising around I actually got map working properly, and the function that I've tested it on works appropriately as well:

accelerate f (x:xs) = map (accelerateList f xs) xs

Works wonderfully. Thanks for the help guys!